# How to extend Angular HttpRequest parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

Hi I'm form AngularJS and newer to Angular.

- **AngularJS**

In AngularJS $http service, I could add some customized configurations to a specific HTTP request:

```
 $http.post('api/data-source/item'.assign(opts), opts.parameters, **ignoreUnauthorized**).then(...)
```

Like the `ignoreUnauthorized` options for this RestAPI to bypass the global http interceptor:

```
responseError: function(response) {
    if (response.status === 401 && !response.config.**ignoreUnauthorized**) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('error:unauthorized', response);
        return $q.defer().promise;
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
}
```

- **Angular4.3+**

But in Angular HttpClient we can't add such property to the options because TypeScript never allowed me to do it.
And I also try to extends the `HttpClient` to add extra options:

```
export interface AppHttpParams {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    body?: any;
    **ignoreUnauth**: boolean;
}

export function applicationHttpClientCreator(http: HttpClient) {
    return new AppHttpClient(http);
}

@Injectable()
export class AppHttpClient {
    public constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
    ...
}
```

But the customized option **ignoreUnauth** seems not comes with the HttpRequest object, all property in HttpRequest object seems the default(output from Chrome console):

```
HttpRequest {url: "http://...", body: null, reportProgress: false, withCredentials: false, responseType: "json", …}
  -body:null
  -headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
  -method:"GET"
  -params:HttpParams {updates: null, cloneFrom: null, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: Map(0)}
  -reportProgress:false
  -responseType:"json"
  -url:"http://..."
  -urlWithParams:"http://..."
  -withCredentials:false
  -__proto__:Object
```

Is there any way to add my own option to the `HttpRequest` in Angular like AngularJS? Or there is other way to extends the `HttpRequest` options ?

Comment: just pass params as string, this should work fine `this.http.get('localhost', {params: {'ignoreUnauth': 'true'}}).subscribe();`

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution @lssbq?

Answer (score 2):

I am using http headers to achieve this.

Just set needed value to the custom http header:

```
new HttpHeaders().set("X-my-custom-header", string | string[]);
```

Then you can remove them in http interceptor (to avoid public visibility)

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const request = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers
                 .delete("X-my-custom-header")
    });
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => this.handleHttpError(err, req))
    );
  }
```

And you can use that value in handleHttpError (as you pass original request there):

```
const myCustomHeaderValue = req.headers.getAll("X-my-custom-header");
```